# Generating expanded time series data from existing series in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

Well, I searched for the to this solution for long but I can't find it, even though I believe it will be something pretty easy to do. I have a time series, in 1 hr intervals for one year. What I want to do is to create fake data for next years, by tinkering with my original data just a bit. For example, if my original data looks like that

```
Date standard   Estimated production 

1/1/2016 7:00   0,0  
1/1/2016 8:00   0,0  
1/1/2016 9:00   16,3  
1/1/2016 10:00  29,4   
1/1/2016 11:00  40,6  
1/1/2016 12:00  33,9
```

(it continues like that until the end of the year), I would like to create fake data that for each respective date, is similar.

```
Date standard   Estimated production 

1/1/2017 7:00   0,01  
1/1/2017 8:00   0,03  
1/1/2017 9:00   16,1 
1/1/2017 10:00  29,3  
1/1/2017 11:00  40,8  
1/1/2017 12:00  33,1
```

The above changes are of course totally random, the production should be increased or decreased by a number within a set limit. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you ask for a C&P solution? .. show us your approach, then we can help.

Comment: Do you want to add a random noise to your data of this year?

Comment: The best option for me would be indeed to add random noise. What I have done so far is just to add or subtract a number from the original dataframe values, depending on if the row is odd or even:                                
pvnew[::2] = pvnew[::2]+0.05
pvnew[1::2] = pvnew[1::2]-0.05

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#using-offsets-with-series-datetimeindex) to shift the index by one year (and then you can modify the values as you want).

To generate noise, you could look at numpy [random](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.random.html) utils.

```
import numpy as np
# Same values as 2016, but dates shifted by 1 year (2017)
fake_data = df.loc['2016'].copy()
fake_data.index = fake_data.index + pd.DateOffset(years=1)

# Add gaussian noise, with same standard deviation of production
noise = np.random.randn(len(fake_data)) * fake_data['production'].std()
fake_data['production'] = fake_data['production'] + noise

new_data = pd.concat([data, new_data], axis=0)
```

Comment: I would prefer to add some noise, not add a specific value.

Comment: I thought the core of your question was how to have the same dates/times one year later. Modified my question with an example of fake data, but there are many ways to do that and depends on the kind of data.